# Automatic rollback of implicit transaction(s) for multiple statements?

Tags: sqlite

When multiple statements are submitted together --separated by semicolons(`;`) but in the same string-- and are NOT wrapped in an explicit transaction, is only a single implicit transaction created or is an implicit transaction created for each statement separately?  Further, **if one of the later statements fail and an automatic rollback is performed, are all of the statements rolled back?**

This other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28351660/1261752) almost satisfies my question, but wording in the official documentation leaves me puzzled.  In fact, this may seem like a duplicate, but I am specifically wondering about **implicit** transactions for multiple statements.  The other answer does not explicitly address this particular case.

As an example (borrowing from the other question), the following are submitted as a single string:

```
INSERT INTO a (x, y) VALUES (0, 0);
INSERT INTO b (x, y) VALUES (1, 2); -- line 3 error here, b doesn't have column x
```

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) says

> Automatically started transactions are committed when the **last** query finishes. (emphasis added)

and

> An implicit transaction (a transaction that is started automatically, not a transaction started by BEGIN) is committed automatically when the **last** active statement finishes.  A statement finishes when its prepared statement is reset or finalized. (emphasis added)

The keyword **last** implies to me the possibility of multiple statements.  Of course if an implicit transaction is started for each individual statement, then taken individually each statement will be the "last" statement to be executed, but in context of individual statements then it should just say **the** statement to emphasize the context being one single statement at a time.

Or is there there a difference between prepared statements and unprepared SQL strings?  (But as I understand, all statements are prepared even if the calling application doesn't preserve the prepared statement for reuse, so I'm not sure this even matters.)

In the case of all statements being successful, the result of a single commit or multiple commits are essentially the same, but the docs only mention that the single failing statement is automatically rolled back, but doesn't mention other statements submitted together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sqlite3_prepare` interface compiles the *first* SQL statement in a query string. The `pzTail` parameter to these functions returns a pointer to the beginning of the *unused* portion of the query string.

For example, if you call `sqlite3_prepare` with the multi-statement SQL string in your example, the first statement is the only one that is active for the resulting *prepared statement*. The `pzTail` pointer, if provided, points to the beginning of the second statement. The second statement is not compiled as a prepared statement until you call `sqlite3_prepare` again with the `pzTail` pointer.

So, no, multiple statements are not rolled back. Each implicit transaction created by the SQLite engine encompasses a single prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks.  Rather than coding with the sqlite C/C++ API directly, I am using the .Net bindings and other tools.  I realize now that the tools are executing multiple statements not as a batch, but handling the individual statement processing.  It was deceiving, as though sqlite handled multiple statements automatically.  It is a challenge trying to interpret the documentation properly when the various interfaces and tools all handle things differently.

Comment: For reference, here's a [link to  sqlite_prepare](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) docs that also describe this behavior.

Comment: Yes, the [tag:sqlite3] tag is supposed to be used for the C library, but it is often used for questions that are utilizing wrappers for that library. It gets hard to tell without additional programming language tags sometimes.

Comment: Although my personal context was with the other tools, I was asking to get an answer exactly as you posted in context of the underlying API.  I had seen the `sqlite3_prepare` function before, but had missed the critical part about it only processing one statement AND I thought that perhaps I was overlooking some details of the transaction processing for multiple statements.  So in this case it was tagged appropriately I think, but I will definitely use the specific tags if I have questions about other wrappers/bindings in the future.

Comment: Well, that's good then. Usually one can tell from the context of the question whether it's about a wrapper or the actual C library, so I wouldn't worry about it *too* much. And yes, I agree this question was tagged appropriately, as it seems to read pretty clearly to be about the C API itself.